# Get Data receive data from Yandex maps Google maps 2gis maps

Tags: html

## **Good afternoon, I need your help, I will be very glad if you help, I'm tired of manually copying everything, there are proposals for cooperation for these companies so that we can contact them**

## **Please tell me how I can copy or to obtain from the service "Yandex Maps, Google Maps, 2GIS"**

## **Instagram Facebook, WhatsApp, Telegram, YouTube, Facebook, all links to the website and all links to social networks from the Real Estate Agency?**

## **In the format text or html format files**

## **From these countries of the world:**

## **Australia**

## **Azerbaijan**

## **Armenia**

## **Belarus**

## **Hong Kong**

## **India**

## **Kazakhstan**

## **China**

## **Kyrgyzstan**

## **Malaysia**

## **Russia**

## **Singapore**

## **USA**

## **Tadjikistan**

## **Uzbekistan**

## **I attached screenshots of how everything looks**